# Error with embed_notebook, getting plotly to work on Jupyter

Tags: r, plotly, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to have embedded R plotly charts in Jupyter

I am following https://plot.ly/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks/

But stuck at `"Make sure that both pandoc.exe and pandoc-citeproc are available in your local python installation folder (or Jupyter environment if you have setup a separate environment)."`

I found the pandoc.exe and pandoc-citeproc. But not sure on where to copy those files.

Based on the Anaconda Prompt my environment is `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\`
But even after copying the files there I still get the error of: "Error in embed_notebook(gg): x must be a plotly figure"

I also ran the command `.libPaths()`
and added the files to that location and get the same error

Jupyter is working, I can make regular ggplot2 plots

```
p <- ggplot(data = test_df, aes(x = day, y = spend)) +
geom_point(aes(text = paste("Country:",country_level)), size = 4) +
geom_smooth(aes(colour = affiliate_country_level_3_name, fill = country_level)) + facet_wrap(~ country_level)

(gg <- ggplotly(p))


embed_notebook(gg)
```

I can plot p using ggplot alright

`test_df` is a data.frame, `day`: Date; `country_level`: Factor; `spend` is num

I installed Python using Anaconda.
Please advise and let me know what else I can provide

Thank you

Comment: Some minimal code will help. If it was a pandoc issue it generally throws an error like pandoc is unavailable etc. Can you share what goes into 'gg' ?

Comment: @royr2 Added in the code with an Edit, thank you

Comment: Seems okay to me. Can you share `test_df` as well? For windows, you should need to paste the two pandoc related files in the same folder where `python.exe` resides. Its probably not inside \AppData\Local. Check the actual install location. \ProgramFiles\ or \ProgramFiles (x86)\.

Comment: I get the same error when trying out the example code from Plotly so I don't believe their to be an issue with test_df. same code works in Rstudio as well. I did a search for python.exe and did not find any matches in \ProgramFiles\ or \ProgramFiles (x86)\ is there a way to find the location using Jupyter? Thank you

Comment: The easiest way is to find it: make a new Python notebook, and run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Output: C:\Users\mynamer\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe   I put the pandoc files there and get the same error

Comment: I am told that there might be some issue with Anaconda and plotly. Could you just try installing python from here https://www.python.org/downloads/ or maybe try Miniconda instead? The tutorial also seems to be updated here  https://plot.ly/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks/

Comment: A fresh install solved the issue, thank you @royr2

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Got the same error.

Comment: Hi @FissehaBerhane, I had to uninstall anaconda and try again to solve the issue.