# Plotly R not working with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter, plotly

I want to incorporate Plotly graphs in my Jupyter notebook but I'm getting a 404 error when I try to display a graph:

[image: Error]

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609768/error-with-embed-notebook-getting-plotly-to-work-on-jupyter)

```
import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

Gives me this location for Python. I have the two Pandoc files in this directory as and all the files needed as mentioned on [Plotly's page](https://plot.ly/r/using-r-in-jupyter-notebooks/).

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I have also tried reinstalling Anaconda and Pandoc but I'm still getting this error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a plotly account? You may need to login into it within your notebook with something similar to this:

```
import plotly
plotly.tools.set_config_file(plotly_domain='domain')


from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.plotly as py
print __version__ # requires version >= 1.9.0
import plotly.graph_objs as go


init_notebook_mode() # run at the start of every ipython notebook to use plotly.offline
                     # this injects the plotly.js source files into the notebook
py.sign_in(username='xxxx', api_key='xxxx')
```

Comment: I tried `Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="your_plotly_username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="your_api_key")` before that code above and It's still giving me 404

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in MacOS. In the console, it can be seen that it's looking for .html.embed but the file which is created is .html.
I have tried,
1) reinstalling Pandocs
2) Had to reinstall Cairo as package pbdZMQ was not getting installing properly.

This is the workaround I did,

```
p <- plot_ly(ds, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers", group = group, size = size)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), "index.html")
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("index.html"), collapse="\n")
display_html(rawHTML)
```

This is not the best solution, but for the time being this works for me.

Comment: When I do this instead of getting "404 Not Found" it's blank. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Warner Can you open your index.html in a browser and see if you are able to get the plot. And also make sure that following libraries are imported `library(xtable)
library(IRdisplay)
library(repr)`

Comment: I opened the index.html file in a browser and the plot appears. I loaded IRdisplay, xtables, and repr (though I'm not sure how the last 2 incorporated in the above code). I'm still getting just blank space.

Comment: does the following code work `display_html("<span style='color:red; float:right'>hello World</span>")`?

Comment: Yes that code works. It seems like anything more complex doesn't work.

Comment: Then I guess it would be because, your installation of IRdisplay in R might not have happened perfectly. During installation of IRdisplay other dependencies are also installed. Some of these dependencies are compulsory while others and not. Try reinstalling IRdisplay once again.

Comment: @Warner any luck ?

Comment: No - I tried doing that and now the kernel dies whenever I try to run any R code.